# How do I write a MYSQL spatial query to find all polygons (rectangle) that contain any points in a table?

Tags: polygon, point, sql, mysql

Something like:

```
SELECT * from polygons WHERE bounds CONTAINS(SELECT geom_point from points)
```

Can someone help me out with the syntax? Bounds will always be a rectangular polygon and everything is in lon/lat. I could just check that each points lat/lng is between the min/max lat/lng of each polygon - but I cannot figure out the syntax to get MYSQL to loop / check all polys vs all points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MYSQL is not a true spatial database - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394645/mysql-spatial-contains-shows-wrong-result

Comment: "As of MySQL 5.6.1, corresponding versions [of spatial functions] are available that use precise object shapes. These versions are named with an ST_ prefix. For example, Contains() uses object bounding rectangles, whereas ST_Contains() uses object shapes." via http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-contains

Comment: I realise this, but since my polygons are rectangles, there shouldnt be a problem.. im sure this query is possible.. i guess it just comes down to syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a polygons table with rectangular polygons, and a points table called points, both with geometry columns called "geom", this should return any polygons that contain any of the points:

`SELECT polygons.id FROM polygons, points WHERE CONTAINS(polygons.geom, points.geom);`

Comment: For some reason the CONTAINS function didn't work, but I ended up using this same syntax but pulling out the min/max long/lats of each box and just checking that a points long/lat was BETWEEN the polygon's bounds. This syntax seems correct though, so i will accept it as the answer - just seems that mysql spatially is a bit of a pig.

Comment: Most recommend PostGIS over MySQL spatial for this reason.  PostGIS has much more spatial functionality and is likely to be more bug free.